# How to update multiple columns of a table using another tables data in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables A , B

A

```
Id  Col1  Col2 Col3
100  Null Null  0
```

B

```
Id   Colx   Colz Coly
100  1234    10   4           
100  2345    12   4
```

Expected Result:

```
Id  Col1  Col2 Col3
100  1234 2345  4
```

I am trying to get the `Colx` of table B into `Col1`,`Col2` respectively based on `Colz` however not getting the expected results.
below is my query -

```
 UPDATE    a
  SET       a.Col1 = CASE WHEN b.Colz=10 THEN b.Colx END,
            a.Col2 = CASE WHEN b.Colz=12 THEN b.Colx END,
            a.Col3=b.Coly
  FROM      A a
            JOIN B b  ON b.Id = a.Id
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the same table twice with different conditions like this:

```
UPDATE    a
  SET       a.Col1 = b1.Colx 
            a.Col2 = b2.Colx,
            a.Col3=b1.Coly
  FROM      A a
  JOIN B b1  ON b1.Id = a.Id AND b1.Colz=10 
  JOIN B b2  ON b2.Id = a.Id AND b2.Colz=12
```